# Supervision for backups (scripts) on Centos

Tags: backup, bash, centos-7

I manage about 40 servers with Centos 7 remotely. Each one has a backup script (in bash) which copies files to the NAS. After the backup everyday it sends a mail to me if it is successful or not. Sometimes it is very confusing to find out which server faulted, because if the network fails I don't get a mail with information about backups. So then I have to find which server is missing. Is there some simple open source solution where I could see results? Something like if script is successful, let it know to the master server where a table with all server results for each day is? Or do you have any other solution?